# Python to .cpp and back again with ctypes via an .so

Tags: python, c++, gcc, ctypes

I'm doing something stupid, but not seeing what... I've reduced my problem to the below (absurd) example - but it highlights where my issue is - I'm clearly not able to pass data into and/or return from, c++, coherently.

test.cpp

```
extern "C"
double reflect(double inp){
    return inp;
}
```

The above is compiled with:

```
g++ -c -Wall - Werror -fPIC test.cpp -o testO.o
g++ -shared -o testSO.so testO.o
```

Output file definitions are included only as I'd use them in real-problem

.py

```
import ctypes
hdl = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(r"C:\Windows\path\to\testSO.so")
```

So, my returns

```
hdl.reflect(1)
>>> 1    (no ctypes conversion, but erm, OK)

hdl.reflect(1.1)
>>> Failure (this is expected)

hdl.reflect(ctypes.c_int(1))
>>> 1   (right well, c_int to c_double looks like it could implicitly work)

hdl.reflect(ctypes.c_float(1.1))
>>> 1006192077   (WTF?!?)

hdl.reflect(ctypes.c_double(1.2))
>>> 858993459    (WTF?!?!)
```

OS is windows 10, compiler is minGW-W64  8.1.0, python is 3.8 (anaconda)

I've ran DLLs before and I've compiled my own .c into python modules before - but for the life of me I cannot see what I'm doing wrong here.....!?!

edit: Corrected typo as pointed out by Topological Sort (path to .so was correct in code, was missing trailing " here)

Comment: I have no answers, but some observations of what I had to do to get this kinda working. Had to take out `-Wall`; had to change `r"C:\Windows\path\to\testSO.so` to `"./testSO.so"` (you need a trailing ", and the path can be relative). ...Then I found `hdl.reflect(1)` was returning 0. I put a line in the test.cpp file to print the parameter; it also is 0. So the problem may relate to passing in, not returning. I'm using python3, python 3.9.7, and g++ 11.2.0.

Comment: Duplicate of [\[SO\]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610333/c-function-called-from-python-via-ctypes-returns-incorrect-value/58611011#58611011)

Comment: Thanks Cristi, you indeed had the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object files and shared libraries do not contain any information about the types of function parameters or return types, at least not for C linkage functions.

Therefore `ctypes` has no way of knowing that the function is supposed to take a `double` argument and return a `double`.

If you call it with anything else than `ctypes.c_double` as argument, you will have undefined behavior. But you can set the argument types up for automatic conversion to the correct `ctypes` type (see below).

`ctypes` also assumes that the return type is `int`. If that is not the case, you are supposed to set the return types correctly before calling. In the following I also set up the argument types so that `ctypes` automatically uses the correct type in calls:

```
reflect = hdl.reflect
reflect.argtypes = [ctypes.c_double]
reflect.restype = ctypes.c_double
reflect(1.2)
```

Comment: Alos note that the implicit conversion mentioned here is done by the `ctypes` package. All this has nothing to do with C/C++ implicit conversion rules. The C/C++ rules are applied at compile time not at runtime.

Comment: @JakobStark Yes, maybe I shouldn't have used the term "implicit conversion" which has a technical meaning in C and C++. I have clarified that a bit.